# How can I add the selected row that has been deleted to a backup database?

Tags: vb.net, phpmyadmin

```html
Private Sub Delete1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete1.Click
        Dim mResult
        Dim ObjConnection As New MySqlConnection()
        mResult = MsgBox("You are really want to delete the slected record?",
        vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Removal Confirmation")
        If mResult = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ObjConnection.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=;database=equipment"
        ObjConnection.Open()
        Try
            Dim ObjCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            ObjCommand.Connection = ObjConnection

            ObjCommand.CommandText = "delete from equipment where asset_code='" & Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value & "'"
            ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Finally
            ObjConnection.Close()
        End Try

        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow)

    End Sub
```

This is my code for the button when the selected row is deleted, I want to insert it to a new database

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, I think about two in particular:

*Create a trigger over equipment table that will be called when a delete statement is executed. If you're on SQL Server you can look up into the special 'deleted' table which handles all records to be deleted by the delete statement, you can use this to store the record in another database. In MySQL this equivalent special table is named 'OLD'.

*DON'T execute a delete statement, just use a "logical delete". This means on adding a reference to each record on each table (like a column) which will determinate if the record is 'active' or 'deleted'. So when deleting an item just change that flag from '0' (active) to '1' (deleted), and when  querying data add an additional condition, to which you will indicate if the record is active or deleted.

The later option is actually the preferred way and it's what is used on high level enterprise apps (like from Oracle). It guarantees that you will have all the possible historical information, which many users/customers will prefer. Just use a delete statement  when you'd wish to clean the database, deleting information that you will no longer need, or that has been already backed up.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Gustavo's logical delete but since the following has been in use I will show you. I wrote the following Stored Procedure...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCoffee
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Insert DeletedCoffees
    SELECT * From Coffees
    Where ID = @ID
    Delete From Coffees
    Where ID = @ID
END
```

I still tip toe around SQL Server and Triggers are outside of my experience.